# How to change the level of img src attribute

Tags: jquery

```
<img class='imgR' src='../img/gold_01.png' alt='img'>
<img class='imgR' src='../img/gold_02.png' alt='img'>
```

I want to change the level of `src` attribute from `../img/` to `img/`

js

```
    $('.imgR').each(function() {
    var a = $(this).attr('src');
    a.replace('../img', 'img');

});
```

I got the error - `Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined`

Comment: Now I see the what is the problem. I cannot change `src` if an image in fact does not exists. I should change this using php, probably. Anyway, thanks a lot. Let's say solved,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in DOM ready. I think that is the problem.

```
$(function(){
   $('.imgR').each(function() {
      var a = $(this).attr('src');
      $(this).src(a.replace('../img', 'img'));
   });
});
```

I presume that you are accessing the element, even before it existed.

Answer (score 1):

Working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4wYfg/

```
$('.imgR').each(function() {
var a = $(this).attr('src');
var b=a.replace('../img', 'img');
    alert(b);
});
```